# ExtJs 5.1 - put html with javascript inside a Ext.panel.Panel

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I have a **html/javascript** file, which i obtained from [this website](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/09/10/Adding-a-file-display-list-to-a-multifile-upload-HTML-control) **(my_site.html)**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Proper Title</title>
<style>
    #selectedFiles img {
        max-width: 125px;
        max-height: 125px;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Files: <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple accept="image/*"><br/>
        <div id="selectedFiles"></div>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
        <script>
    var selDiv = "";
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
    function init() {
        document.querySelector('#files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
        selDiv = document.querySelector("#selectedFiles");
    }
    function handleFileSelect(e) {
        if(!e.target.files || !window.FileReader) return;
        selDiv.innerHTML = "";
        var files = e.target.files;
        var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);
        filesArr.forEach(function(f) {
            if(!f.type.match("image.*")) {
                return;
            }
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var html = "<img src=\"" + e.target.result + "\">" + f.name + "<br clear=\"left\"/>";
                selDiv.innerHTML += html;               
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(f); 
        });
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to use this **html/javascript** file inside an [Ext.panel.Panel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel).

[This thread](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?151081-script-tags-inside-panel-html&s=b2666d92c8d75d3066ae80b1f3eb1ac9) describes *two possible approaches* of combining **html/javascript** files with **Ext.panel.Panel**, but neither of them is working in my case.
Problem is: The html-Form does display, but the javascript is not executing.

Here is **approach Number 1** using [Ext.ComponentLoader](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ComponentLoader):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- ext imports -->
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/ext-5.1.1/build/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext-5.1.1/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext-5.1.1/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/ext-theme-neptune.js"></script>

        <script type ="text/javascript">    
            Ext.onReady(function(){             
                var my_panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                    frame: true,
                    title: 'my_panel',
                    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                    loader: {
                        renderer: 'html',
                        scripts: true,
                        url: './my_site.html',
                        autoLoad: true
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is **approach Number 2**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- jquery imports -->
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

        <!-- ext imports -->
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/ext-5.1.1/build/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext-5.1.1/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext-5.1.1/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/ext-theme-neptune.js"></script>

        <script type ="text/javascript">    
            Ext.onReady(function(){             
                var my_panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                    frame: true,
                    title: 'my_panel',
                    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                    listeners: {
                    render: function(panel) {
                        panel.body.update($.ajax({type: "GET", url: './converter_panel_card_0.html', async: false}).responseText, true);
                    }
                }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

I want to know why both approaches are not working and how to let the html/javascript-file execute like in [this demo](http://www.raymondcamden.com/demos/2013/sep/10/test0.html) with the difference that it is inside a Ext.panel.Panel.

Comment: Have you tried using url as "my_site.html" instead of "./my_site.html" in the first approach?

Comment: If you haven't read my post carefully enough: The form is displaying (so the path to the html must be correct), but the javascript inside the html file is not executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why both approaches are not working

Because the JavaScript code in your html/javascript file relies on the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event which *has always already been fired before* your Ext.panel.Panel can even start loading the file. This is why your `init()` is never executed.

> how to let the html/javascript-file execute like in this demo with the
>   difference that it is inside a Ext.panel.Panel

No direct way. You have to either:

- Modify the JavaScript code in your html/javascript file ensuring that `init()` is executed upon loading the file into your Ext.panel.Panel. For example, make your `init()` execute after a tiny delay sufficient for the form elements to populate: `setTimeout(init, 50);`; OR
- Use an iframe to load your html/javascript file in it so that the `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired. For example, an [`IFrame`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ux.IFrame) component as the only fit-item in your Ext.panel.Panel:

```js
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    requires: [
        'Ext.ux.IFrame'
    ],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {
        xtype: 'uxiframe',
        src: 'file.html'
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you give examples for your approaches?

Comment: I dont know how to integrate your first approach, but the second one with Iframe is working.

Comment: It is actually good that the second approach worked for you and not the first. The first one is not that clean as it is mixing alien html/javascript directly into Ext JS space.